# NullReferenceException after creating new form instance

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

So I am programming some kind of a member data-storage application and I'm getting a NullReferenceException when I try to create a new form instance.

Code in the main:

```
List<Object> list_objects = objects.get_Objects();

        try
        {
            New_Object obj = new New_Object(this, objects, list_objects.ElementAt(lv_data.FocusedItem.Index));
            obj.Show();
        }catch(NullReferenceException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No object selected.");
        }
```

Code in "New_Object"

```
public New_Object(Main main, Objects objects, Object obj)
    {
        btn_create.Text = "Cahnge";
        btn_create.Click += btn_change_Click;
        this.obj = obj;
    }
```

There is an existing object in list_objects with the index of 0 and the lv_data.FocusedItem.Index is also 0, so why is this not working?

Thanks for helping and explaining

Comment: Means that either `list_objects` or `lv_data`  is  `null`

Comment: Which of your variables is null ?

Comment: Did you try stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen or `objects` or `lv_data.FocusedItem` or `btn_create`

Comment: The exception details will let you know exactly which line it occurred in. Simply set a breakpoint there and inspect everything that could be null.

Comment: It says btn_create is null. But why? It is in the form.

Comment: Ok I suck :D I forgot "InitializeComponent();" <,<